# Kubernetes: How to set boolean type variable in configMap

Tags: kubernetes, configmap, kubernetes-secrets, kubernetes-deployment

I want to set a boolean variable in configMap (or secret):

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: ConfigMap
metadata:
  name: env-config
  namespace: mlo-stage
data:
  webpack_dev_server: false
```

But when I apply it, I get the following error:

```
The request is invalid: patch: Invalid value: "map[data:map[webpack_dev_server:false] metadata:map[annotations:map[kubectl.kubernetes.io/last-applied-configuration:{ blah blah blah}]]]": unrecognized type: string
```

I have tried to change the value to Off/No/False, all having the same problem.

It seems that the value of the keys in the data map can only be string, I have tried to change the value to "false", the yaml file is OK, but then the variable becomes a string but not boolean.

what should I do if I want to pass a boolean as value?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Values in a [ConfigMap](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/configuration/configmap/) must be key-value string values or files.

Change:

```
data:
  webpack_dev_server: false
```

To:

```
data:
  webpack_dev_server: "false"
```

To your question:

> what should I do if I want to pass a boolean as value?

You may handle this in the application, transform from `string` to `bool`.

Comment: Thank you @Jonas for the answer, so this confirms that only strings can be passed as values in configMap.

Answer (score 2):

Change the following code like this:

```
data:
  webpack_dev_server: false
```

to

```
data:
  webpack_dev_server: "\"false\""
```

Below mentioned error can also be solved quickly in the same way.

> error when creating "test.yaml": ConfigMap in version "v1" cannot be handled as a ConfigMap: json: cannot unmarshal number into Go struct field ConfigMap.data of type string.